# Can you use a two handed weapon with light shield?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons, shield

Can you use a two handed weapon with light shield?

I'm confused over the wording in [[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=7)] ...

> Description: While you’re using a light shield, you can use your shield hand to hold another item, to climb, and the like, but you can’t make attacks with that hand or with anything in it.

Your shield hand is usable, but you can't attack with it, so a second weapon can't be used, but does that preclude the two handed weapon ?

Comment: Maybe edit the final question in the post to more closely ask the same thing as the title question? Reading 'No' just after reading 'does that preclude the two handed weapon' is a bit confusing at first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No**

You are considered to be attacking with your second hand on the weapon.

You are holding the weapon in your other hand, thus it violates the "with anything in it" clause.