# Is there a way to use a shield with a glaive?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, shield, weapons

I'm making a character for a Halloween one-shot, and want to use a glaive *and* a shield.

Glaives have the [two-handed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) property, which requires the use of two hands to **attack** ... but  your attack is only a small portion of the whole round.

I found a similar question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14407/can-you-use-a-two-handed-weapon-with-light-shield), but that is dealing with 4e ... and while it might seem counter-intuitive to have two things in the same hand, I haven't found any rules that specifically state that you *can't*.

Obviously, DM fiat is a thing, so I'm looking for RAW reasons that would allow the use of a glaive with a shield.

Comment: Have you considered having your character be a Thri-Kreen?

Comment: @Kirt: I hadn't thought of that TBH.

Comment: @Kirt Thrikreen can't use a shield in their extra arms. At least the version released in spelljammer can use its secondary arms to interact with items or use a light weapon, nothing else.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I hadn't seen the new version, thank you.  Back in my day, a thri-kreen could use its four arms to wield two glaive-like gythkas at once and its two legs to walk uphill both ways.

Comment: Yeah, I think at some point they decided that dual-wielding heavy weapons was probably A) unbalanced and B) rather silly. I don't recall ever seeing art depicting that; usually it shows a single gythka plus one or more knives, short-swords, or chatkcha throwing blades (any of which is totally doable with the current version).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Unfortunately, 2 + 1 > 2.

> ***Two-Handed.*** This weapon **requires two hands** when you attack with it. This property is relevant only when you attack with the weapon, not when you simply hold it.

> ***Shields.*** A shield is made from wood or metal and **is carried in one hand.** Wielding a shield increases your Armor Class by 2. You can benefit from only one shield at a time.

If you are carrying your shield in one hand, it isn’t free to be used to wield the glaive.

In case it wasn’t completely obvious, “requires two hands” in the Two-Handed property description means it requires two hands be available and free to manipulate the implement. No, *it does not mean “as long as you have two hands you can use the implement even if those hands are otherwise occupied”.*

This understanding is confirmed in the description of the magic item Animated Shield:

> While holding this shield, you can speak its command word as a bonus action to cause it to animate. *The shield leaps into the air and hovers in your space to protect you as if you were wielding it, leaving your hands free.*

It specifically mentions “leaving your hands free” because while you are wielding it normally, *your hand isn’t free*.

Donning and doffing a shield both take an action, so there are no shenanigans you can do with dropping the shield.

Answer (score 2):

### No, but you can use the *shield* spell

As [Thomas' answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/201818/75095) elaborates, there is no way to *attack* with a glaive while you have donned a *physical shield*, as the shield does not leave both of your hands free.<sup>1</sup>  You also cannot get rid of and re-equip a shield fast enough, as both donning or doffing one to benefit from its AC bonus take an action (p. 146 PHB). So, there is no RAW support for this idea.

For what it is worth, I think the reason that you do not find rules support here is that for balance reasons you have to sacrifice the AC bonus a shield provides to obtain a damage boost that 2-handed weapons provide. It's intentional. All the fighting feats or styles are also designed with this trade-off in mind, and none of them allow you to ignore it.

However, you can obtain access to the *[shield](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shield)* spell, either by taking a level in an appropriate spellcasting class such as sorcerer or wizard, or by taking a feat such as Magic Initiate, and you can take the War Caster feat to perform the required somatic component even if you have a weapon such as a glaive in both hands. This will allow you to use your Reaction to create an even better *shield*, worth +5 to AC, a limited number of times per day. You'll need to decide for yourself if that benefit is worth the investment of character development.

---

<sup>1</sup> You of course can *use* a glaive while you have donned a pysical shield for other stuff like tapping the floor for traps, but I think that is not what you are after, you want to *attack* with the glaive while enjoying the AC benefit of a shield.

Comment: I feel like "No, but you can use the *shield* spell" would be a more appropriate header. Since OP is obviously talking about a physical shield, your header reads like "Yes, but actually no".

Comment: @ThomasMarkov, good suggestion, updated. Btw, good job with the magic shield to suss out that even though the core rules never explicitly say a hand that you hold a weapon in is not free (probably because it is obvious), this must be the case.